# Setting up two code igniter applications in Cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, cpanel

I am trying to set up two code igniter applications on my web hosting server. 
Both are using the  same system folder which I have placed it in 
: 
/public_html so it is /public_html/system : for system files 
and my two applications I have placed them in a folder called applications 
: 
/public_html/applications so it is /public_html/applications/app_1 and /public_html/applications/app_2

I decided to create a different index files for the  two applications with app_1 using index.php and app_2 using index_2.php.

I have managed to access app_1 successfully using my main url but I cannot be able to access my app_2 at all, since I don't know what to use as my base_url in app_2.

The following are my respective urls for the  two applications 
 app_1 :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
```

And index for my app_1 is :

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

app_2:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
```

and I decided to add my index file for app 2 
so it is

```
 $config['index_page'] = 'index_2.php';
```

Please can some one advise on how I can be able to access app_2 from the  url? 
Or what changes should I make on the  settings process?

Comment: on what basis you are accessing the application. put the condition to the index.php which is outside of application folder and accordingly give the application name. So it will take the application based on the condition

Answer (score 1):

**System and application folders**

/public_html/system    ->system folder

/public_html/applications/app_1 -> application 1

/public_html/applications/app_2 -> application 2

**Index pages.**

/public_html/index.php -> to access application 1

/public_html/index_2.php  -> to access application 2

NO NEED TO UPDATE BASE URL - (`$config['base_url'] = '';`)

Adjust the path of application folder in index.php and index_2.php and index_2.php

**index.php :**

```
$application_folder = 'applications/app_1';
```

**index_2.php :**

```
$application_folder = 'applications/app_2';
```

**URL**

application 1 : example.com/index.php

application 2 : example.com/index_2.php